# prohibit that the returned reference of a function is overridden by a assignment

Tags: c++, c++17

is there any way, in C++ 17,  to prohibit that the returned reference of a function is overridden by a assignment like the following:

```
class Error{
  public:
    Error& doSomething(int);
};

Error a;
Error b;

Error.doSomething(0) = b; // how do I prohibit this?
```

The reason why I want to do this is, so that this:

```
class Error{
  public:
    void doSomething(int);
};

Error myFunction(void) {
  if(true){
    a.doSomething(1);
    return a;
  }
}
```

may be reduced to:

```
class Error{
  public:
    Error& doSomething(int);
};

Error myFunction(void) {
  if(true){
    return a.doSomething(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Soooo `operator=(Error&) = delete`? `The reason why I want to do this is, so that this:` I do not understand, how is it related?

Comment: If you don't want the return type to be modified, then make it `const`.

Comment: Do you only want to prohibit assigning directly to the return value, or do you want to prohibit all assignment to the object (i.e. `Error& e = a.doSomething(0); e = b;`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `Error` either by value or by constant reference, both variants prohibits using result as left side of assignment

```
class Error{
public:
    Error doSomething(int);
}

Error myFunction(void) {
  if(True){
    return a.doSomething(1);
  }
}
```

or

```
class Error{
public:
    Error const & doSomething(int);
}

Error const & myFunction(void) {
  if(True){
    return a.doSomething(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return `const Erro&` instead of `Error&`. However, this would limit you to only using the `const` interface of `Error`.

Alternatively, you could define a kind of a *[proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) class* that has the assignment operator deleted and return an object of this class instead of a reference to the original class object.

Returning a proxy instead of `const Error&` will allow you to use the non-`const` interface of `Error` as well.

```
class Error;

struct ProxyError {
   ProxyError(Error& error): error_(error) {}
   ProxyError& operator=(const ProxyError&) = delete;
   operator Error&() { return error_; }
private:
   Error& error_;
};
```

`Error::doSomething()` would return a proxy object by value, `ProxyError`:

```
class Error {
public:
    ProxyError doSomething(int) & {
       return ProxyError(*this);
    }
};
```

This way, the following assignment:

```
auto main() -> int {
   Error a;
   Error b;
   a.doSomething(0) = b ;
}
```

will result in a compilation error:

> `error: overload resolution selected deleted operator '=' a.doSomething(0) = b ;`